# How can I use a script to convert a .wav and .webm saved on server into a .mp4 and save it on the server

Tags: php, mysql, audio, video

Ok. So I have a website where I use a form to record information on the user and store it in a MySQL database. After you submit the form, it opens a page where there is a video and audio recorder setup. (At the top of this file, in the php, it also handles the form input.) So I have this part all done and it is working perfectly. The only problem is that the video/audio recorder saves two files which are named after the user who submitted the form, a .webm with video, and a .wav with the audio. What I want to do is make a script that combines the two into one .mp4 or .avi. The plugin I used for the recording is [Here](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/Html5_Video_Audio_Recorder). I just want some advice on where to start. I am also fine with using some kind of plugin or something, because it is a private project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can't be used to do audio/video files conversions. To achieve what you want you have to use `FFmpeg` which is a command-line tool that runs on Linux and Windows.
If you don't have a least a VPS or dedicated hosting, there is no chance that your shared hosting provides this library.

With a small search on the internet I've found that: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: I wrote a php script to automatically generate ffmpeg code based on mysql database. That way I can just download all the files to my computer and paste the code. Very simple.

Comment: Of course, PHP can be used to convert files, why not? You can read and parse any file and output whatever you want.